# How do I get the results of a second line of a HTTP POST into a string?

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am making an android app that retrieves information via HTTP POST. The problem is that while I can retrieve the relevant data, it doesn't want to output on different lines. For example, I have the following simple php script:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["test"])) $test="no test\n"; 
else $test=$_POST["test"];

echo "hello1 \r\n";
echo "hello2";
?>
```

On a normal HTTP Post, it would responsd "hello1" on one line, and "hello2" on the next line. However, when I receive it in Android, it comes out as "hello1 hello2".
   Preferably I would want to get the second line into another string rather than on the same line, but I'm not sure how to do this on Android.

The code for the Android app is:

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    String urlParameters = ("test=");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString()); //print result
```

Comment: You mean you only want to retrieve the second line value (hello2) and ignore the first line? Or is it that your issue is that the \r\n disappeared when received by Android, therefore both strings are now in "one line"?

Comment: @Aplinescrambler Sorry, I think I was a bit unclear in my explanation. To answer your question, it is the second one. Both strings are now in "one line". I would like to have both values, but on different lines, that way I can parse them and use them as variables later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your while, extract the second line like this

```
int line = 0;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
line++;
if(line==2)
   response.append(inputLine);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I modified it a bit in that I still needed the first line, but everything else works perfectly. For anyone else who comes across this thread, I changed it to:                                                                    int line = 0;
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  line++;
  if(line==1)
      response1.append(inputLine);
  if(line==2)
     response2.append(inputLine);
   }
  
  in.close();